# Binary Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

**The given problem:**
Use friend function for getting the private variable and operator overloading for calculating the total number of goals by each side of the team. I'm completely new to C++ and unable to figure out how to fix this error.
**What I've tried:**

```
Player operator-(Player &P1, Player &P2)
{
    Player P;
    P.goal=P1.goal+P2.goal;       
    return P;
}
```

**Error:**

```
main.cpp:104:17: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Player’ and ‘Player’)
    
main.cpp:26:8: note: candidate: Player operator-(Player&, Player&) 
 Player operator-(Player &P1, Player &P2)
        ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:8: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:104:14: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Player&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Player’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1196:5: note: candidate: template decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)
     operator-(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1196:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:104:18: note:   ‘Player’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1189:5: note: candidate: template decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:1189:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:104:18: note:   ‘Player’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:336:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:105:18: note:   ‘Player’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
```

I'm completely new to C++ and unable to figure this out.

Comment: Your `Player` class should have a default constructor that initializes its members.  Right now, this code invokes undefined behavior : `Player p; std::cout << p.goal;`, since `goal` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not passing `Player` as a reference in the operator solves the issue:

```
Player operator-(Player P1, Player P2) {
    Player P;
    P.goal=P1.goal+P2.goal;       
    return P;
}
```

As well as passing them as a reference to `const`:

```
Player operator-(const Player &P1, const Player &P2) {
    Player P;
    P.goal=P1.goal+P2.goal;       
    return P;
}
```

Error messages I got were very helpful: `no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Player’ and ‘Player’)`, while the candidate was: `‘Player operator-(Player&, Player&)’`.

Now we see it all. The operator returns by value (returns rvalue), while parameter types are non-`const` lvalue references, `Player&`.

And then **the error says for itself**:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Player&’ 
to an rvalue of type ‘Player’
```

Comment: @EurekaChan you're welcome! By the way, welcome to SO! Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you consider one as such.